# How to Set BucketLifeCycleRule in Minio?

Tags: java, kotlin, amazon-s3, bucket, minio

After creating a Minio bucket, I set the bucket's lifecycle rules. The LifeCycleRule takes up the expiration variable that is set for just 1 day. When checking the status of my bucket through minio client (mc), `mc ilm ls mycloud/bucketName` , I notice that the Lifecycle rule was successfully applied on to the designated bucket. However, when checking back on Minio after 1 day, the bucket is still there. Is there something else that I need to add to the LifeCycleRule in order to delete Minio Bucket properly?

Note, I've been using [Minio SDKs Java Client API](https://docs.min.io/docs/java-client-api-reference.html#setBucketLifecycle) as reference.

---

```
fun createBucket(bucketName: String){
   client.makeBucket(MakeBucketArgs.builder().bucket(bucketName).build())
   setBucketLifeCycle(bucketName)
}

private fun setBucketLifeCycle(bucketName: String){

   // Setting the expiration for one day.
   val expiration = Expiration(null as ZonedDateTime?, 1, null)

   var lifeCycleRuleList = mutableListOf<LifecycleRule>()

   val lifecycleRuleExpiry = LifecycleRule(
     Status.ENABLED,
     null,
     expiration,
     RuleFilter("expiry/logs"),
     "rule 1",
     null,
     null,
     null)

   lifecycleRuleList.add(lifecycleRuleExpiry)
   var lifecycleConfig = LifecycleConfiguration(lifecycleRuleList)
 
   // Applies the lifecycleConfig on to target bucket.
   client.setBucketLifecycle(SetBucketLifecycleArgs.buider()
     .bucket(bucketName).config(lifecycleConfig).build())
}
```

**Questions**

- Am I missing something more on my LifeCycleRule?
- Could it be that the bucket does not get automatically deleted because it has objects inside of it?

  - I did notice on the minio client that when the bucket has items on it, `mc rb mycloud/bucketName` will fail to remove the the bucket, but forcing it with `mc rb -force mycloud/bucketName` will successfully remove it. Is there a way to speficy "force" on the lifecycle parameters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lifecycle rules apply to objects within a bucket, not to the bucket itself.

> An S3 Lifecycle configuration is a set of rules that define actions that Amazon S3 applies to a group of objects.

(ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html)

So, this bucket **will not** be deleted (even) when all the objects in it are expired via ILM policies.

Comment: So to recap what you are saying, the BucketLifeCycle is used to set rules on all of the objects within the designated bucket. The LifeCycleRules do not apply to the bucket itself, thus the bucket will never be deleted. Thanks.